# Object name in rendering JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, ruby-on-rails-4

In Rails 4, when rendering an object, for example User, I am getting this:

```
{ "id" : 4 , "name" : "John" }
```

While, when using rails-api gem, I am getting this:

```
{ "user" : { "id" : 4, "name" : "John" } }
```

What would be more correct, and how can I make Rails to return the object key?

Right now I am doing this in my controller:

```
render json: @user
```

Comment: Use `include_root_in_json` option : http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html

Comment: Oh thanks. May I ask, what is the deal with this namespacing? I see maaany different opinions..

Comment: IDK, just found this option while trying Backbone.js (http://backbonejs.org/#Model-parse)

Answer (score 0):

To explain why you're seeing this behavior...

In Rails 4 they changed "changed `ActiveModel::Serializers::JSON.include_root_in_json` default value to `false`" ([source](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#active-model)).

On the other hand, the `rails-api` gem, by default, includes a root element.  You can easily disable it globally or on a per call basis... the docs explain it [here](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers).

Regarding your "what would be more correct" question...

I think the answer is subjective. If i were starting an app from scratch I would probably make my client adhere to the defaults provided by the backend used.  It seems like it would be the path of least resistance when dealing with future upgrades.